# Space between inline-block and inline element

Tags: css

I have an `inline-block` element, with `inline` elements on left and right.

Why there is white space only on the right of the `inline-block`?

```css
span{
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
span:nth-child(2){
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>inline </span> 
<span>inline-block</span>
<span>inline </span>
```

Also, Why there is an one pixel height difference for `inline-block` element?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4tbvavz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an inline element's boundary lies between two spaces the space that *follows* the boundary (outside the inline element) is removed, leaving the space within the inline element. In your case, the space that is trimmed off is the newline that separates your `span` elements. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model):

> For each inline element (including anonymous inline elements), the following steps are performed, treating bidi formatting characters as if they were not there:
>
> 4. If 'white-space' is set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line',
>
>    2. any space (U+0020) following another space (U+0020) — even a space before the inline, if that space also has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap' or 'pre-line' — is removed.

Note that this is only the case with inline boxes, i.e. `display: inline` elements — not inline-blocks. Appending a space to the content of your inline-block element will not cause the space after it to be collapsed away.

The height difference mainly has to do with how the height of inline elements vs inline-blocks is calculated, which is an entire topic in itself. See sections [10.6.6](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#block-root-margin) and [10.8.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#leading) of the spec.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the white space after the word `inline` in the first span, there will be a space.

```css
span{
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
span:nth-child(2){
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>inline</span> 
<span>inline-block</span>
<span>inline</span>
```

Comment: and, what about the height difference ?

Comment: OK you got me there, I don't know sorry.You'll have to manually set a `height` to get them the same size. In this instance `17px`. (padding adds `20px` on height overall.) @afelixj

Answer (score 1):

inline elements has small spaces around them by default, the size of space is determined by font-size.. to achieve no space result you need to reset font-size to 0 on wrapping element, check edited fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5n0goq85/

```
<div class="wrap">
<span>inline </span> 
<span>inline-block</span>
<span>inline </span>
</div>

span{
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
span:nth-child(2){
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap{
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because on `inline-block` elements space between elements is actually visual on the screen and in your OP there is whitespace between `span` elements:

```css
span{
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
span:nth-child(2){
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>inline </span><span>inline-block</span><span>inline </span>
```